# Dealing with Partials as a modal

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

As the title suggest I want to create like a modal where a user can select a region that they're from using Partials in C# before using the application. I was looking around and fell into a rabbit hole of just adding a partial like a form that appears on the page all the time. The behavior that I am expecting is once the user navigates to application a modal appears and before advancing they select a region. According to the region they select the data will change according to the region they have selected. I don't know if this is even possible because I can't find anything remotely close of a partial acting like a modal. Any help or other suggestions would be awesome. TIA

Comment: Your question is too abstract. Please make it more specific.

Comment: I've written an article on using Razor Pages partials with Bootstrap modals: https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/349/razor-pages-and-bootstrap-modal-master-details